# How to import invoice payment information into Sage 500/Mas 500

Tags: sage-erp

We have an existing payment engine that processes credit card and checking. I have created the ability to lookup invoices with a balance, "grab" all the details, and offer customer payment through other means. Now I need to bring the payment information back into Sage 500, so the invoice will be closed. Has anyone out there done this before, or know of stored procedures I should focus on?

PS - I am fairly fluent with SQL. I would like to automate this process, so I am trying the SQL way before involving Data Import Manager.

Comment: Hi David, have you come across the Sage automation libraries? They are part of the Sage 500/1000 FCE/Automation SDK. Which i think are 'free'. What the automation COM interface allows you to do is feed data into the sage system as if a user was accessing the screens themselves. Might be a way of creating invoices and also posting them. The issue you have with a Stored proc approach is the numerous system keys/projects and ultimately tables that need updating. Where as automating the client all that is catered for.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I ended up using the stored proc "spARapiPendingCashReceiptIns". It was not easy. I had to read the entire procedure to figure out what staging tales to load and ultimately get the payment loaded into the "pending" tables. From there, the office manager will see the newly created batch and finalize. I haven't seen anything about an FCE/Automation SDK. Is it a DLL loaded in the install of  Sage? What is the local location of it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can import AR Cash receipt into the [Sage 500](http://wwww.SageProDev.com) by populating staging table and running spARapiPendingCashReceiptIns stored procedure.